# mySQL Database: Reset AutoIncrement Fields

Tags: mysql, reset, auto-increment

while the development of websites we use the database to test & all... which consumes a lot from auto generated (auto increment) attributes series... how to reset everything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're deleting the records when you're done testing, a `TRUNCATE` command will delete all records and reset the autoincrement value.

Answer (score 3):

`ALTER TABLE _TABLE_ AUTO_INCREMENT=1`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, avoiding transactions and resetting the autoincrement counter could be to combine the select to get the next available id and the insert itself;

INSERT INTO tablename (id, somefield1, somefield2) SELECT max(id)+1, 'test', 5 FROM tablename