# Active Record - Get the second, third.. item in a database (without ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How to I retrieve the second, third .. entries in a database. I don't want to use the auto incrementing id generated by rails.

As I am deleting entries from my database, so the ID continues to increase.

So my DB would have

```
id : 210 (Even thought it's currently the first value)
id : 211 (Even thought it's currently the second value)
```

I know "Phone.first" will return the first how do I get the second.

Sub Question-
**Destroy_all/delete_all**  - 
 only removes the item, Can I remove all entries from the DB and have the DB id's start from one without dropping the table. As I ran into problems.

Comment: Resetting the autoincrement ID is possible through an SQL statement, though it is database specific. According to your wording I assume you use MySQL so check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246959/mysql-database-reset-autoincrement-fields

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Say you want the fourth user:

```
 @users = User.limit(4)
 @fourth_user = @users[3]
```

Concerning your second question, `destroy_all` should do the trick since it triggers all callbacks. Be sure to add `:dependent => :destroy` in  your relationships.

Comment: This works, especially on MySQL, but keep in mind that the returned data may not be always in the same order if no "order" clause is defined. In Postgres for example, the returned records are not in the same order as they are were inserted.

Comment: Or more succinctly:

`@fourth_user = User.limit(1).offset(3).first`

Comment: Thanks for your reply apneadiving, I'm having a slight problem;
I'm trying, 
`@fourthChoice = FeedEntry.limit(4)
@fourthChoice_user = @fourthChoice[3]`

When I try to display `<%= @fourthChoice_user %>`, I see <FeedEntry:0x00000103547a50>.

I figure that I wouldn't need a block to display the info.

@phiggy When I try; `@fourth_user = User.limit(1).offset(3).first`, I get the same.

Comment: Yes it's pretty logic, you've to write exactly which attribute you want. For the name: `<%= @fourthChoice_user.name %>`

Answer (score 17):

what you need is

```
#n=2,3,4 etc    
.limit(1).offset(n)
```

Comment: this seems more efficient for large sets.

Answer (score 12):

#### `Model.second` was added to Rails 4.1.8.

So you can use it on Rails versions equal to or greater than that.

`.third`, `.fourth` and `.fifth` were also added to [`ActiveRecord::FinderMethods`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods).